# Replace values based on multiple conditions with groupby mean in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', periods=6, freq='M'), 
                   'value': [3, 3.5, -5, 2, 7, 6.8], 'type': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']})
df['pct'] = df.groupby(['type'])['value'].pct_change()
```

Ouput:

```
        date  value type       pct
0 2013-01-31    3.0    a       NaN
1 2013-02-28    3.5    a  0.166667
2 2013-03-31   -5.0    a -2.428571
3 2013-04-30    2.0    b       NaN
4 2013-05-31    7.0    b  2.500000
5 2013-06-30    6.8    b -0.028571
```

I want to replace the `pct` values which is bigger than `0.2` or smaller than `-0.2`, then replace them with groupby `type` `mean`s.

My attempt to solve this problem by: first, replace "outliers" with extrame values `-999`, then replace them by groupby outputs, this is what I have done:

```
df.loc[df['pct'] >= 0.2, 'pct'] = -999
df.loc[df['pct'] <= -0.2, 'pct'] = -999

df["pct"] = df.groupby(['type'])['pct'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(-999, x.mean()))
```

But obviously, it is not best solution to solve this problem and results are not correct:

```
        date  value type         pct
0 2013-01-31    3.0    a         NaN
1 2013-02-28    3.5    a    0.166667
2 2013-03-31   -5.0    a -499.416667
3 2013-04-30    2.0    b         NaN
4 2013-05-31    7.0    b -499.514286
5 2013-06-30    6.8    b   -0.028571
```

The expected result should look like this:

```
        date  value type       pct
0 2013-01-31    3.0    a       NaN
1 2013-02-28    3.5    a  0.166667
2 2013-03-31   -5.0    a    -1.130
3 2013-04-30    2.0    b       NaN
4 2013-05-31    7.0    b  2.500000
5 2013-06-30    6.8    b      1.24
```

What I have done wrong? Again thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead your both conditions is possible use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and set values in `pct` by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean`:

```
mask = df['pct'].between(-0.2, 0.2)
df.loc[mask, 'pct'] = df.groupby('type')['pct'].transform('mean').values
print (df)
        date  value type       pct
0 2013-01-31    3.0    a       NaN
1 2013-02-28    3.5    a -1.130952
2 2013-03-31   -5.0    a -2.428571
3 2013-04-30    2.0    b       NaN
4 2013-05-31    7.0    b  2.500000
5 2013-06-30    6.8    b  1.235714
```

Alternative solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['pct'].between(-0.2, 0.2)
df['pct'] = np.where(mask, df.groupby('type')['pct'].transform('mean'), df['pct'])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201943/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-replace-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-with).