# How to Fill NaNs in Column of Main Dataframe Based On Conditions Matching Secondary Dataframe of Values to Fill NaNs With Multiple Filler Values

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I need to fill NA values in my main data frame based on a second dataframe I created by the `groupby` and `mean` functions. My original dataframe has about 1.5K NaNs I need to fill so this needs to reproducible at a mass scale. I've created a fake dataframe that's a short quick and dirty imitation of my data using a fake scenario. I can't share my real data with you.

My general idea is:

```
main_data[
          (main_data["Animal_Type"] == mean_data["Animal_Type"]) & 
          (main_data["Cost_Type"] == mean_data["Cost_Type"])
         ] = main_data["Price"].fillna(mean_data["Price"])
```

Obviously, that doesn't work and but that's the general gist of how my logic is working. I found t[his answer][1] but I can't see to apply it properly to my problem. A lot of answers involve `mask` or assume my data is pretty small with a single value to replace all my NaNs with. I have about 50 different means in my original dataset that are uniquely paired with a "Animal Type" per each "Cost Type". My original data frame is about 30K observations long full of unique observations too. I can map but that's only for a single column. I'm fairly new to coding so a lot of the other answers were too complicated for me too understand and alter too.

main_data

```
mean_data.head(10)

   **Pet_ID Animal_Type Cost_Type   Price**
0   101     Goat        Housing     6.0
1   102     Dog         Housing     6.0
2   103     Horse       Housing     NaN
3   104     Horse       Housing     5.0
4   105     Goat        Housing     3.0
5   106     Dog         Feeding     3.0
6   107     Cat         Feeding     6.0
7   108     Horse       Housing     6.0
8   109     Hamster     Feeding     5.0
9   110     Horse       Feeding     3.0
```

mean_data

```
    Animal_Type Cost_Type   Price
0   Cat         Feeding     4.500000
1   Cat         Housing     5.000000
2   Chicken     Feeding     5.000000
3   Chicken     Housing     4.500000
4   Dog         Feeding     3.000000
5   Dog         Housing     6.000000
6   Goat        Feeding     5.000000
7   Goat        Housing     5.000000
8   Hamster     Feeding     5.250000
9   Hamster     Housing     3.000000
10  Horse       Feeding     3.500000
11  Horse       Housing     5.666667
12  Rabit       Feeding     3.000000
13  Rabit       Housing     3.000000
```

My Reproducible code:

```
random.seed(10)

random.seed(10)

main_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Pet_ID", "Animal_Type", "Cost_Type", "Price", "Cost"])

main_data["Pet_ID"] = pd.Series(list(range(101,150)))
main_data["Animal_Type"] = main_data.Animal_Type.apply(lambda x: random.choice(["Dog", "Cat", "Rabit", "Horse", "Goat", "Chicken", "Hamster"])) 
main_data["Cost_Type"] = main_data.Animal_Type.apply(lambda x: random.choice(["Housing", "Feeding"])) 
main_data["Price"] = main_data.Price.apply(lambda x: random.choice([3, 5, 6, np.nan])) 
main_data["Cost"] =  main_data.Cost.apply(lambda x: random.choice([2, 1, 3, np.nan])) 

mean_data = main_data.groupby(["Animal_Type", "Cost_Type"])["Price"].mean().reset_index()
```

**Edit:** I have put together two solutions but I wouldn't say it's the more elegant or dependable. Probably not the most efficient too.

```
main_data = pd.merge(
    main_data,
    mean_data,
    on = ["Animal_Type", "Cost_Type"],
    how = "left"
)

main_data["Price_z"] = main_data["Price_x"].fillna(main_data["Price_y"])
```

**Edit 2**: I've added a "Cost" Column with NaNs. I don't want this column touched but would like to use the same methodology with this column we're using for the Price column.
[1]: [Replace values based on multiple conditions with groupby mean in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710697/replace-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-with-groupby-mean-in-pandas)

Comment: @The.B The second dataframe is one I created through the group by function and taking the mean after two levels of grouping. I can't use the unique identifers for this one, unfortunately.

Comment: @The.B I didn't think concat works on dataframes of different lengths. But I also only need to replace the NaNs--not the entire column.

Comment: Have you tried fillna()

Comment: yes--I edited with the solution I just came up with but I would really like to not have to append/add new columns to my data frame. I'd just like to run through the column and plug those values in based on the matching of the two other columns. I'm worried it's not the most reliable method--at least the one I came up with

Comment: Drop the column you dont need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to fill NA values in my main data frame based on a second dataframe I created by the `groupby` and `mean` functions.

You don't need that step. You can do this in one step by grouping into multiple dataframes, applying mean on each individual dataframe, and filling NA values within just that dataframe.

So, instead of creating the `mean_data` dataframe, do this:

```py
def fill_by_mean(df):
    df["Price"] = df["Price"].fillna(df["Price"].mean())
    return df

main_data = main_data.groupby(["Animal_Type", "Cost_Type"]).apply(fill_by_mean)
```

Each individual call to fill_by_mean() sees a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    Pet_ID Animal_Type Cost_Type  Price
11     112       Rabit   Feeding    NaN
34     135       Rabit   Feeding    3.0
38     139       Rabit   Feeding    3.0
```

Then it gets the mean of the price column and fills NA values using that. Groupby then concatenates all of the individual dataframes back together.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer but is there a way to keep this answer contained to the column labelled "Pirce". It helps a lot but it also fills in the rest my NAs in other columns. I have two specific columns with NAs that I had hoped to apply this answer to while preserving the NAs in other columns because those columns can't be filled by the same method of mean which I'll be filling by other methods. I've added a "Cost" Column if that helps any

Comment: @EX_Tenn Yes, you just need to select the column before doing fillna. See edit.