# Replace outliers with groupby average in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following multi-index data frame, where ID and Year are part of the multi-index. Some numbers for the variable ROA are unreasonable, so I want to replace every ROA value that is larger than the 99th percentile of ROA in the overall data frame by the average of its company (the same for everything smaller than the 1th percentile).

```
    ID  Year  ROA
    1   2016  1.5
    1   2017  0.8
    1   2018  NaN
    2   2016  0.7
    2   2017  0.8
    2   2018  0.4
```

In a different thread I found the following approach ([Replace values based on multiple conditions with groupby mean in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710697/replace-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-with-groupby-mean-in-pandas)):

```
    mask = ((df['ROA'] > df['ROA'].quantile(0.99)) | (df['ROA'] < df['ROA'].quantile(0.01)))
    df['ROA'] = np.where(~mask, df['ROA'], df.groupby('ID')['ROA'].transform('mean'))
```

However, this does not work for me. The maximum and minimum values of my data frame do not change. Does someone have an idea why this could be?

EDIT:

Alternatively, I thought of this function:

```
   df_outliers = df[(df['ROA'] < df['ROA'].quantile(0.01))|(df['ROA'] > 
   df['ROA'].quantile(0.99))]

   for i in df_outliers.index:
      df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('ID') == float(i[0])) &
      (df.index.get_level_values('Year')==float(i[1])), 'ROA'] = 
      float(df.query('ID == {} and Year != {}'.format(i[0], 
      i[1])).ROA.mean())
```

However, here I run into the problem that in the df_outliers.index some companies are mentioned several times because their ROA is an outlier in several years. This makes the function defeat its purpose, as it is currently it only excludes one year from the calculation of the mean, and not several.

Comment: You probably want to "invert" the mask, if I understand correctly - i.e. `np.where(~mask, df['ROA'], df.groupby('ID')['ROA'].transform('mean'))`

Comment: Oh, the ~ somehow got lost in my post, I had it like that in my code, but it is not working. I edited my post, thanks

Comment: When I use `~mask` with your example data, my highest and lowest values do get replaced

Comment: You're right, I just tested it with some random toy data and it also works, but for some reason not on my data frame. Do you have any insight on why this could happen?